# NAT configuration for EIP (Elastic IP) in Asterisk

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, nat, asterisk, sip

When running Asterisk on Amazon EC2 with an EIP, what are the NAT configurations for Asterisk?

```
[general]
nat=yes
externip=xxx.yyy.zzz.vvv
localnet=192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 ; RFC 1918 addresses
localnet=10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0      ; Also RFC1918
localnet=172.16.0.0/12           ; Another RFC1918 with CIDR notation
localnet=169.254.0.0/255.255.0.0 ; Zero conf local network
```

Apparently, [EIC uses NAT](https://serverfault.com/a/708291/132080):

> If your EC2 instance is in a private subnet in your VPC, then it can
>   use your NAT to make outbound connections. The outside world would see
>   it's IP address as your NAT's IP address, but the NAT's IP address
>   would never "be" the Public IP address of the instance.

Overview of [how EIP works](http://www.rightscale.com/blog/cloud-management-best-practices/dns-elastic-ips-eip-and-how-things-fit-when-upgrading-server):

> Before going into an example, let's review how the Elastic IPs work:

...

> Remember that each instance has an internal IP address and an
>   external (public) one, which is translated to the internal one. If two
>   external IPs were translated to the same internal IP then inbound
>   packets would arrive fine, but sorting out outgoing packets (i.e.
>   determining which external IP address to assign to outgoing packets)
>   would be very difficult. Hence, the limitation of a single external IP
>   address per instance at any given point in time.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud#Elastic_IP_addresses) (for my reference):

> Elastic IP addresses Amazon Elastic IP
>
> Amazon's elastic IP address feature is similar to static IP address in
>   traditional data centers, with one key difference. A user can
>   programmatically map an elastic IP address to any virtual machine
>   instance without a network administrator's help and without having to
>   wait for DNS to propagate the binding. In this sense an Elastic IP
>   Address belongs to the account and not to a virtual machine instance.
>   It exists until it is explicitly removed, and remains associated with
>   the account even while it is associated with no instance.

Getting down to nuts and bolts, in the [context of SIP and Asterisk](http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/sip_nat_oneway_or_no_audio_asterisk.html):

> 1.3. Different types of NATs and firewalls.
>
> There are several ways UDP might be handled by a specific NAT or
>   firewall implementations, these are categorized into:
>
> 1.3.1 Full Cone NAT
>
> A full cone NAT is one where all requests from the same internal IP
>   address and port are mapped to the same external IP address and port.
>   Furthermore, any external host can send a packet to the internal host,
>   by sending a packet to the mapped external address.
>
> 1.3.2 Restricted Cone:
>
> A restricted cone NAT is one where all requests from the same internal
>   IP address and port are mapped to the same external IP address and
>   port. Unlike a full cone NAT, an external host (with IP address X) can
>   send a packet to the internal host only if the internal host had
>   previously sent a packet to IP address X.
>
> 1.3.3 Port Restricted Cone:
>
> A port restricted cone NAT is like a restricted cone NAT, but the
>   restriction includes port numbers.
>
> Specifically, an external host can send a packet, with source IP
>   address X and source port P, to the internal host only if the internal
>   host had previously sent a packet to IP address X and port P.
>
> 1.3.4 Symmetric Nat:
>
> A symmetric NAT is one where all requests from the same internal IP
>   address and port, to a specific destination IP address and port, are
>   mapped to the same external IP address and port. If the same host
>   sends a packet with the same source address and port, but to a
>   different destination, a different mapping is used. Furthermore, only
>   the external host that receives a packet can send a UDP packet back to
>   the internal host.

It sounds like EIC uses "full cone" NAT.  What would be the Asterisk settings for NAT, then?

Answer (score 1):

Externip should be set to external ip

Localnet set to local network(check using ifconfig).

Sure

```
nat=comedia,force_rport
```

(nat=yes not work in modern versions).

```
;   nat = no                ; Do no special NAT handling other than RFC3581
;   nat = force_rport       ; Pretend there was an rport parameter even if there wasn't
;   nat = comedia           ; Send media to the port Asterisk received it from regardless
;                           ; of where the SDP says to send it.
;   nat = auto_force_rport  ; Set the force_rport option if Asterisk detects NAT (default)
;   nat = auto_comedia      ; Set the comedia option if Asterisk detects NAT
```

Comment: This is an old thread but I am wondering if `nat=yes` works in version 15 or above? Also a little explanation of `comedia,rport` would be helpful.

Comment: You should not use nat=yes in version 16. Even if worked at this moment(not sure). Changed above description of current modes. In short comedia,force_rport mean "i know better about client's NAT", which is true for most older phones and low-end softphones without STUN enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the update. We have a NAT on the Asterisk 15.6.1 server. Problem is the voice on the extension (Bria softphone) is not working. Do we have to set a port number for `rport`? So I was wondering what should be the correct configuration for asterisk under NAT.

Comment: Sorry, i not do debug on SO. You have debug yourself or write question with correct info about your nat and settings(including network picture) and wait till someone answer.